# Angular required validation does not let form valid until input is edited

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms

I have a below html where I have implemented HTML5 required property:

```
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>{{question.placeholder}}<span *ngIf="question.required">*</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
                <mat-form-field style="width:100%">
                        <input matInput [placeholder]="question.placeholder" [id]="question.key" [maxLength]="question.maxLength" [formControlName]="question.key"
                            type="email" [required]="question.required"[readonly]="question.readonly" [value]="question.value" (keyup)="checkValue($event, question)"
                            (paste)="checkPasteValue($event, question)">
                        <mat-hint align="end">{{question.value ? question.value.length : 0}} / {{question.maxLength}}</mat-hint>
                    </mat-form-field>

        </div>
```

It is an email field.

[required]="question.required"

Below is a form button which needs to enabled when form is valid.

```
 <button mat-raised-button class="md-primary md-raised pull-right" color="primary" style="margin-right:10px;" *ngIf="isEditMode" [disabled]="!dataEntryForm.valid"
        (click)="updateDataEntry($event)">UPDATE</button>
```

button does not enable until input is dirty, whereas it is pre filled. So it should be satisfied for required. So what should be used in such case?

**EDIT**
Form is pre-filled by using service:

```
 editSectionDataItem(item: any) {
    var me = this;
    // / var decodedItem = this.decodeDataArray([item]);
    // console.log(item, this.originalData);

    var decodedItem = this.originalData.filter(function (originalItem) {
      return originalItem.id == item.id;
    });

    console.log(decodedItem, item);
    var mission = {
      widgetConfig: this.widgetConfig,
      settings: this.settings,
      fields: this.fields,
      isEditMode: true,
      data: flattenJSON(decodedItem[0])
    }
    console.log(mission);
    this._widgetService.missionToOpenDataEntryForm(mission);


  }
```

Comment: How are you prefilling the input?

Comment: @Gobli I am using a service to fill form data.

Comment: Why don't you use [(ngModel)] instead of [value] ?

Comment: @Gobli Thanks It worked. What is reason behind this? Can you explain please. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Sure, I have just posted an answer with the explanation so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[value]`.

`[(ngModel)]` is basically what gives Angular the validation properties of the form. Without it, you can't track the validation state of the input (at least on a template-driven form).

More info about this on the Angular docs, [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel) and [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)